# WSO2 Identity Server - fidp as SAML request parameter causes signature validation error

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I've connected two WSO2 Identity servers per documentation: 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Connecting+Two+Identity+Servers+with+SAML+SSO

From login page I can select to login with external identity provider and login - all good.

Now I want to use URL to go straight to login page at external IDP, using fidp as SAML request parameter.

http://yasassriratnayake.blogspot.ie/2014/11/adding-multiple-federated.html

Again, all good I can land directly on the login page of the external IDP.

However, when I now try to login at the external IDP there is a problem validating the signature at the primary IDP.

```
[2015-10-30 16:12:08,252] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil} -  Request message <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:AuthnRequest AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://localhost.firecrestclinical.com/identity/saml/SSO/alias/fcp" Destination="https://localauth.firecrestclinical.com/samlsso" ForceAuthn="false" ID="a261bg24geadb49245icdjg1d150if4" IsPassive="false" IssueInstant="2015-10-30T16:10:24.935Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://services.firecrestclinical.com/sp/fcp</saml2:Issuer></saml2p:AuthnRequest>


[2015-10-30 16:12:08,253] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.validators.SAML2HTTPRedirectDeflateSignatureValidator} -  Constructing signed content string from URL query string SAMLRequest=fZJfb4IwFMXf9ylI3%2FlXwcxGMG7GzMRFIriHvdVSsAu0rLeY7dsPRDN90Mc295x7cn53OvupK%2BvINQglI%2BQ7HrK4ZCoXsozQLlvaz2gWP02B1hVuyLw1B7nl3y0HY80BuDad7lVJaGuuU66PgvHddh2hgzENENetFKPVQYFxCqE5052QVUKK7tdhqnZFzqUR5tftN7hpunFpJSi4BWuQteimhaTmlO3GkXZB7jj2RgAKWUulGT8ljlBBK%2BDIWi0iRPHY35c4KDnN98EEB6Fg%2BVfp537oiSLohiChAOLI%2F2UALV9JMFSaCGHPD23fs0de5o%2BJ7xEcOJNR%2BImsRCujmKpehBwKbLUkioIAImnNgRhG0vn7mmDHI%2FthCMhbliV2skkzZH1cQOAeRIdGAhmqf%2BzVnBejeCBFTon1tcNjA3phieJLzzDQhHs1Nz2jqXu9Lz4%2Fbw8l%2FgM%3D&fidp=localauth.exostar.com&RelayState=e30%3ADu2FkyYuACS6V_JY-jxkc4etKLCvmdouiPMvVdwzts16Fy7q_LMdRtQxGg-TJg3aFkbKzjZ1xFtPJFfLfdnQFQ&SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23rsa-sha1&Signature=UzlHeX51YOI3vDgzmcQmTMkXp%2FXlwWI3QPHcuJxPlv%2Fh37g5xAnj6nRuDx94ebImAc5RKddIcDnBLnpqxqcnW%2FnguAoDbmcStHyUe%2Bc%2F4fo9ZVPh2P%2BtMhTMrcYyAd3Kj6Z3y8f2B7h%2FVWSNpkxxFkiRNb3FDqm%2F%2FWddAXXrYacRs4kbXAq9zRc%2FuAgo8ms%2BSKSNQN0VhePHu%2F2FfzOQLaN0JZGBXechRN9avrOSHy6I5fCOt%2FPkT81N%2FxzIUOpRT40Yck8JW54IONQoyHONUv0bYzExr4XIyp2KwNe2Z4ZT11ZXjoJgRJ9j8xnC30vyw49ibUtPW8Fn9zRn9WJkwQ%3D%3D


[2015-10-30 16:12:08,254] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.validators.SAML2HTTPRedirectDeflateSignatureValidator} -  Constructed signed content string for HTTP-Redirect DEFLATE SAMLRequest=fZJfb4IwFMXf9ylI3%2FlXwcxGMG7GzMRFIriHvdVSsAu0rLeY7dsPRDN90Mc295x7cn53OvupK%2BvINQglI%2BQ7HrK4ZCoXsozQLlvaz2gWP02B1hVuyLw1B7nl3y0HY80BuDad7lVJaGuuU66PgvHddh2hgzENENetFKPVQYFxCqE5052QVUKK7tdhqnZFzqUR5tftN7hpunFpJSi4BWuQteimhaTmlO3GkXZB7jj2RgAKWUulGT8ljlBBK%2BDIWi0iRPHY35c4KDnN98EEB6Fg%2BVfp537oiSLohiChAOLI%2F2UALV9JMFSaCGHPD23fs0de5o%2BJ7xEcOJNR%2BImsRCujmKpehBwKbLUkioIAImnNgRhG0vn7mmDHI%2FthCMhbliV2skkzZH1cQOAeRIdGAhmqf%2BzVnBejeCBFTon1tcNjA3phieJLzzDQhHs1Nz2jqXu9Lz4%2Fbw8l%2FgM%3D&RelayState=e30%3ADu2FkyYuACS6V_JY-jxkc4etKLCvmdouiPMvVdwzts16Fy7q_LMdRtQxGg-TJg3aFkbKzjZ1xFtPJFfLfdnQFQ&SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23rsa-sha1


[2015-10-30 16:12:08,254]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor} -  Signature validation for Authentication Request failed.
```

I think the problem is that a digest is calculated on message that includes SAML request parameter fidp, and signature validated against a message that doesn't include the FIDP parameter.

Should the fidp SAML request parameter be removed before the signature is calculated from the URL Query string?

The query string associated with the AuthNRequest is stored as session data to cache:

SAMLRequest=fZJRb4IwFIXf9ytI36GAiqwRjJsxM3HRCO5hb7UW7VJa1lvM9u8Hopk%2B6GObe849Od8djX9K6Ry5AaFVggLPRw5XTO%2BE2idok8%2FcGI3TpxHQUoYVmdT2oNb8u%2BZgnQkAN7bRvWoFdclNxs1RML5ZLxJ0sLYCgrHUjMqDBusVwnBmGiGTQonm12O6xGLHlRX2F7cbcJYtMZWCAi5YhZxpMy0UtadsN460CXLHsTUC0MiZacP4KXGCCiqBI2c%2BTRANw69eEMZRPHyOij7fR9G%2BPwx6MQt2%2FraZgRUFEEf%2BrwKo%2BVyBpcomKPSDgRsErt%2FP%2FZgMYhL0vEb%2FiZyV0VYzLV%2BE6vqrjSKaggCiaMmBWEayyfuChJ5Ptt0QkLc8X7mrZZYj5%2BPCIWw5NGQUkK75x17VeTFKO1DklNhcOzw2oBeUKL3UDB1MuNdy1SIa4et96fl5eyfpHw%3D%3D
&fidp=localauth.exostar.com
&RelayState=e30%3ADu2FkyYuACS6V_JY-jxkc4etKLCvmdouiPMvVdwzts16Fy7q_LMdRtQxGg-TJg3aFkbKzjZ1xFtPJFfLfdnQFQ
&SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23rsa-sha1
&Signature=cVVJuIGTy%2BflDRwPqDi0pIwwA4Axsi%2BPN6kQn2KMzD2R97tCQEhzhergx%2BqKr1hGwZbK2DdmRBv18ixnwW%2BfzMg8ezl31k3qE1OtDSk%2B2uDEekIjSOf0pIHCW7%2Brd4Ers4mLSU%2Bpz%2Fff6Bm5GRk50zCnmVwNfsf9tIfbRx5DtzfTo%2FReIwrkImLSLs6F10l%2FDvsWysXKq4EH2TL6qDWpsjqEh%2FMQhcBk%2BAKQHbJZLlI1H0p%2BDcrWjQszKIzYrstpnN7sNTRT0IuyCueB18hNhtF6o2CPIUbnV5x7TZo5DCFGVXnTNFOkP08BzDNpvbGjpms%2B%2BX6eHSMPNoBq40Lxdg%3D%3D

The fidp parameter is included in digest algorithm of signature. Note that the signature shall be different based on the order of these parameters (e.g. if fidp parameter is before relay state or after relay state). However, couldn't find a lot of documentation on this fidp parameter, and specifically didn't see what order this request parameter should have. My assumption is that the entire SAML request should be used to generate signature, and the fidp should not be excluded from the signature calculation.

From debugging WSO2 identity server I can see that the signature of AuthnRequest is validated on receiving a AuthnResponse from the External Identity Server. The method SAML2HTTPRedirectDeflateSignatureValidator#validateSignature is invoked and the SAML2HTTPRedirectDeflateSignatureValidator#getSignedContent builds signed content corresponding to log above:
"Constructed signed content string for HTTP-Redirect DEFLATE ..."

However, the SAML2HTTPRedirectDeflateSignatureValidator#getSignedContent method is not extracting the fidp parameter and doesn't know what order to append the fidp parameter to the string builder. By debugging and adding the fidp parameter correctly to the string, I was able to verify that the signature validates successfully.

Comment: A simple workaround is not to include the fidp parameter as part of the signature calculation in the AuthNRequest. This works.